# open quote is expected for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type <RelativeLayout

Tags: xml

I want to design my XML but i found an error in my program
it said "open quote is expected for attribute "android:id="@+id/OpenButton"" associated with an element type

Here is my code, hopefully anyone can give me a solution?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id=“@+id/OpenButton”
android:layout_width=“match_parent”
android:layout_height=“match_parent”
android:background=“@drawable/blue”
tools:context=“com.example.bluetut.MainActivity” > 
<TextView
android:id=“@+id/label”
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_alignParentRight=“true”
android:layout_alignParentTop=“true”
android:text=“@string/status”
android:textColor=“@color/status” />
<TextView
android:id=“@+id/textView1″
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_alignParentBottom=“true”
android:layout_alignParentLeft=“true”
android:text=“@string/hello_world”
android:textColor=“@color/web”
android:textColorLink=“@android:color/white” />
<Button
android:id=“@+id/ButtonOpen”
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_above=“@+id/textView1″
android:layout_alignParentLeft=“true”
android:layout_marginBottom=“25dp”
android:layout_marginLeft=“25dp”
android:text=“@string/Open”
android:textColor=“@color/open” />
<Button
android:id=“@+id/ButtonSendData”
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_alignBaseline=“@+id/ButtonOpen”
android:layout_alignBottom=“@+id/ButtonOpen”
android:layout_centerHorizontal=“true”
android:text=“@string/Send”
android:textColor=“@color/send” />
<Button
android:id=“@+id/ButtonClose”
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_alignBaseline=“@+id/ButtonSendData”
android:layout_alignBottom=“@+id/ButtonSendData”
android:layout_alignParentRight=“true”
android:layout_marginRight=“24dp”
android:text=“@string/Close”
android:textColor=“@color/close” />
<EditText
android:id=“@+id/TxtInput”
android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
android:layout_alignParentLeft=“true”
android:layout_alignParentRight=“true”
android:layout_below=“@+id/label”
android:layout_marginTop=“26dp”
android:background=“@color/backtext”
android:ems=“10″
android:inputType=“text” >

<requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Look carefully at the quotes.

Starting with the offending tag, you have been using "smart quotes" (`“`/`”`) instead of plain quotes (`"`). Only the latter are allowed. How did you get those quotes into your XML file? Are you using Microsoft Word as an editor?